# How to check hashset for an existing element and then adding a count

Tags: java, hashset, distinct-values

I'm a beginner in Java and is starting to learn how to use hashsets. I have a problem with my practice exercise. The goal is to remove the duplicate description and then adding the count of similar descriptions.

For example I have,

Computer Science - 15
Engineering - 20
Dentistry - 10
Architecture - 11
Computer Science - 25
Dentistry - 7

then the output should only be:

Computer Science - 40
Engineering - 20
Dentistry - 17
Architecture - 11

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //printing summary report
    ArrayList<String>   summaryReport=  new ArrayList<String>();

    final String[] CourseDesc           = {"Computer Science", "Architecture", "Dentistry", "Computer Science"};
    final int[] CourseCount         = {15, 10, 10, 25};

    for (String element: CourseDesc) {
        for(int el: CourseCount){
             summaryReport.add(element + " "+ el);
        }
     }
   System.out.println(summaryReport);
  }
}
```

I'm just stuck on how to add the count of similar descriptions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your full code example please?

Comment: the full code has a thousand lines

Comment: But you haven't written "thousands lines" have you? Please share the code you have written. It's hard to see why you need a HashSet here, a HashMap looks like a much more suitable solution for the problem.

Comment: You should share an working example oft your issue, so wie can reproduce it.

Comment: I already copied a part of the full code that I have an issue on

Comment: How is your current code relevant to HashSet and to the problem description? Now it is even more confusing what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

A smart way to solve you problem would be to use Java Streams:

```
final String[] courseDesc = {"Computer Science", "Engineering", "Dentistry", "Architecture", "Computer Science", "Dentistry"};
final int[] courseCount = {15, 20, 10, 11, 25, 7};

Map<String, Integer> summaryReport = IntStream.range(0, courseDesc.length).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        index -> courseDesc[index], index -> courseCount[index],
        (count0, count1) -> count0 + count1, LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

This creates a Map with the course as key and the sum as value. If the map contains an course and the same course is collected again the lambda expression `(count0, count1) -> count0 + count1` handles it by summing the values. The `LinkedHashMap::new` is to maintain the order.

Now you can print the summary like this:

```
summaryReport.forEach((course, count) -> System.out.println(course + " - " + count));
```

Result:

```
Computer Science - 40
Engineering - 20
Dentistry - 17
Architecture - 11
```

Answer (score 0):

From OP I can see that you need an association key-value container, so the most obvious way will be to use `Map`, check if the value present as a key, if not - add it with `1` counter, if present - add `+ 1`:

```
void test() {
    Map<String, Integer> summaryReport = new HashMap<>();
    String curDesc = "whatever";

    Integer count = summaryReport.get(curDesc);
    if (count == null) {
        summaryReport.put(curDesc, 1);
    } else {
        summaryReport.put(curDesc, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Doing in more tricky way, you can use mutable `AtomicInteger` as a counter:

```
void test() {
    Map<String, AtomicInteger> summaryReport = new HashMap<>();
    AtomicInteger counter = summaryReport.putIfAbsent("whatever", new AtomicInteger(0));
    if (counter != null) {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```